# How do I add other attributes to htmlAttributes?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The code below works, but when I try to add another attribute to `htmlAttributes`, it shows an error that I cannot do this.

@Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form 
control" } });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the next attribute outside of the `htmlAttributes` object by the looks of it. Instead, you want this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form control", style = "background: blue" }})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form control",
                                                      id="id" 
                                                    } 
               })
```